# Angular UI bootstrap datepicker pop-up not working when upgrading to version 0.11 from 0.10

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

The angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker isn't popping up when clicked after upgrading to version 0.11.

I've tried the [recommended work around](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1922#issuecomment-40491716) which is setting

```
is-open="dt.open" ng-focus="dt.open=true"
```

this works when it is enabled on just one calendar but not if there are two on the same page (both open and they are unusable). Anyone know a better work around that does not pollute the scope?

I've also tried changing ng-focus to ng-click and had no luck with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two separate datepicker will require 2 distinct variables to control them:

```
is-open="dt.open" ng-focus="dt.open=true" // first datepicker

is-open="dt2.open" ng-focus="dt2.open=true" // second datepicker
```

Comment: Any Idea how to encapsulate is-open variable into control and don't mess scope